# Python/Psychopy: checking if a point is within a circle

Tags: python, psychopy

I want to know the most efficient way to check if a given point (an eye coordinate) is within a specific region (in this case a circle).

Code:

```
win = visual.Window([600,600], allowGUI=False)

coordinate = [50,70] #example x and y coordinates 

shape = visual.Circle(win, radius=120, units='pix') #shape to check if coordinates are within it

if coordinate in shape:
    print "inside"
else:
    print "outside"

>>TypeError: argument of type 'Circle' is not iterable
```

My x and y coordinates correspond to one point on the window, I need to check if this point falls within the circle whose radius is 120 pixels.

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: Besides the straightforward geometric way of checking the (squared) distance beween point and center?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PsychoPy's `ShapeStim` classes have a `.contains()` method, as per the API:
http://psychopy.org/api/visual/shapestim.html#psychopy.visual.ShapeStim.contains

So your code could simply be:

```
if shape.contains(coordinate):
    print 'inside'
else:
    print 'outside'
```

Using this method has the advantage that it is a general solution (taking into account the shape of the stimulus vertices) and is not just a check on the pythagorean distance from the stimulus centre (which is a special case for circles only).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it needs to be that complicated:

```
center=(600,600)
radius=120
coordinate=(50,70)

if (coordinate[0]-center[0])**2 + (coordinate[1]-center[1])**2 < radius**2:
    print "inside"
else:   
    print "outside"
```

Comment: Could you tell me what the '-circle[0]' part does?

Comment: Shifts the coordinates you're testing to be relative to the center of the circle, rather than to the origin, so that you can see if the test points are within a certain radius of the center of the circle.